# How do I perform error handling in ASP.NET MVC 3 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post-redirect-get

I have an Account controller which have:

- LoginForm (get action)
- Login (post action)
- RegisterForm (get action)
- Register (post action)

In another controller's index action i use render them as:

- Html.RenderAction("RegistrationForm", "Acount");
- Html.RenderAction("LoginForm ", "Acount");

Everything works ok and I can register a new user, login and validate with unobtrusive validation.

The problem is when do some back-end validation in Register/Login action and if there is an error I don't know how to transfer the error to be rendered.

I've tried with PRG pattern and it works ok. I get the error displayed on the form with the preserved data, but PRG is not the way to do it.

What is an alternative solution to this problem without using ajax to validate or move those methods in the controller where the RegistrationForm/LoginForms are used?

I want to skip using TempData due to session usage in the background.

EDIT CODE SAMPLE:

```
class AccountController : SomeBaseController{

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult RegistrationForm()
    {
        return PartialView(new RegisterUser());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser(RegisterUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var _user;// create domain user from Register user Model;

            var _validationOutput = _userService.DoSomeAwsomeServerSideValidation(_user);// do some custom validation

            if (_validationOutput.IsFault)
            {
                // we preseve tempdata in base controller OnActionExecuted
                _validationOutput.ErrorMessages.ForEach(x => ModelState.AddModelError(_validationOutput.ErrorCode, _validationOutput));
                // redirect to home controller custom error occured
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", user);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("RegistrationInfo");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("SomeUserInfoAction");
    }
```

}

```
class HomeController : SomeBaseController {
 Index(){
    return View();
 }}

HomeControllerMarkup { 
    @{Html.RenderAction("RegistrationForm", "Acount");} 
    @{Html.RenderAction("LoginForm", "Acount");}
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about displaying a validation error for the information that has been entered or is this for an error message that needs to be displayed on a separate error page?  The reason I ask is you say PRG is not the way to to it?  Can we see your controller actions to understand this better?

Comment: Not a way to do it since PRG is to prevent x form post which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add errors to your `ModelState` within your post controller using:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", @"You didn't perform task XYZ");
```

You should then be able to return the view and display the errors in a validation summary:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Login was unsuccessful because...")
```

Comment: I do that, but the problem that i can not return the view that hosts the RegisterForm and LoginForm since it is in another controller.
If i redirect to action, then i must prg and use tempview which i dont want to use it.